# Instance name is displayed as "unknown" on Eureka Dashboard instead of service name

Tags: service, registry, netflix-eureka

I am working on microservices with Spring boot and using eureka as server. I have registered my service on Eureka server but on Eureka Dashboard, service name is displaying as "Unknown "instead of service name which i configured in application.yml.

below are the both yml config
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

---

eureka:
   client:
        serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    instance:
        appname: reporting-engine
server:
  port: 0
instance:
  preferIpAddress: true
spring:
    application:
          name: reporting-engine

---

Comment: any idea ?I am getting this error .

Comment: I have mentioned spring.application.name=sample

Answer (score 2):

try to create a **bootstrap.yml** file and add this :

```
spring.application.name = instanceName
```

Comment: I always wonder what is the difference between bootstrap.yml and application.yml. The fact that i know is bootstrap.yml contains the properties like application name and server port on which it runs.

Comment: I added in application.properties file and it also worked for me.
spring.application.name=product-service

Comment: fact is bootstrap.yml runs before application.yml. if same property is wriiten in both file the application.yml value will be executed

Answer (score 1):

In your applicaton.yml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: yourname
eureka:
  instance:
     instanceId: ${spring.application.name}
```

where the "instanceId" is important to meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

Change property default-zone by defaultZone. I share you what works for me.

**application.yml**

**Eureka Server**

```
   eureka:
     instance:
       hostname: localhost
     client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
       registerWithEureka: false
       fetchRegistry: false
     server:
       enable-self-preservation: false

   server:
     port: 8882
```

**Eureka Client**

```
   spring:
     application:
       name: customer

   eureka:
    client:
      eureka-connection-idle-timeout-seconds: 60
      serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:8882/eureka/
      healthcheck:
        enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. In my application.properties file on the spring client app trying to connect to `eureka` server, I had a typo `application.name=servicename`

After correcting it to `spring.application.name`, instance name showed up on `eureka` dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

create bootstrap.properties and add :

```
spring.application.name = <instanceName>
```

then , in application.properties set :

```
eureka.instance.hostname=<hostname>
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${random.int} // to have a unique instance id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your IDE and try to keep your application name in lowercase letters

( spring.application.name=order-service )

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue if you are adding properties in `app.yaml` file make sure to provide proper spaces for the right config to get added, below is my `app.yaml` file and it worked for me.

```
server:
  port: 8089
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:3306/productdb
    username: root
    password: root
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  application:
    name: product-service

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

It works like this `spring.application.name=product-service`.  Therefore we provide one tab or 2 spaces here after 'spring' while writing 'application' then one more tab when writing 'name' and further the name.